# How to implement Serial Port Profile Link Command used in ConnectBlue Bluetooth Module?

Tags: c, bluetooth

I am trying to implement Bluetooth using "connect-blue-oem-spa-331" module using UART protocol and using MSP430 as base controller. I'm using Embedded C as a language of programming. 
Everything just works fine until I reach to Serial Port Link Command "**AT*ADCP**". Every time I get response as ERROR. I have tried with both options by keeping **ECHO ENABLED** and **ECHO DISABLED**.

**p_cmd = "AT*ADCP=XXXXXXXXXXXX,0,0,0\r";**

this is my command. 'X' represents the Bluetooth confirm device address which I confirm when I execute DEVICE_INQUIRY command.

The module through which I am executing all these commands is always MASTER and will initiate pairing and communication process. As a safety I have kept it non-discoverable.

How can I implement the Serial Port Profile Link command without getting error when I confirm the bluetooth device using DEVICE_INQUIRY command.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with blue tooth for last 4 months. I had faced above issue in early days. And after running through documentation available for product I solved the issue. I thought to reply this question which I've asked.

I was using *Connect Blue OEM-SPA-331i* classic Bluetooth module in my project, and was using Serial Port Profile to implement Bluetooth commands. 
When I inquire devices I get the list of Bluetooth Devices available and discoverable in the vicinity(mine was CLASS-I Device); and lists them as (***48 bit MAC Address,Class of Device***) i.e. ( 001234ab987f,786545) of the discovered Bluetooth Module.
When I'm trying to establish Serial Port Profile Link, it was required that I must write address of peer device to be connected over Serial Port Profile in Serial Port Adapter. The order of the commands should be

Inquire discoverable devices
Write the desired peer device address to Serial Port Adapter, remember it in power cycles.
Establish Profile Link.

This way I resolved my issue of link not getting established.